# How to delete amazon cognito user using C#?

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I want to delete cognito user using my lambda c# application. I noticed that we have the CognitoIdentityProvider SDK but i cant find examples in the internet about how to use it to delete a user using the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a C# guy myself, but you need to use the `AdminDeleteUser` API-Call ([documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminDeleteUser.html)).

The [documentation of this method in the .Net SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=CognitoIdentityProvider/MCognitoIdentityProviderAdminDeleteUserAdminDeleteUserRequest.html) will probably help you.

First you create an [`AdminDeleteUserRequest` Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CognitoIdentityProvider/TAdminDeleteUserRequest.html) which you then pass on to the aforementionend `AdminDeleteUser` method from the SDK and if your permissions etc. are sufficient you should be good.